# Excel function to show result afyer we have chosen multiple variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need your help cause i am stuck here.
The task is : you have 3 cells, each one filled by a drop down list.

Based on the chosen comination i want to  set a specific result in cell 4.

E.g.
Cell1 is list of colours
Cell2 is list of materials
Cell3 is list of names
Cell4 we need result based on the above

I need formula, that will look up for all of these variables(over 50 of them) and if we have cell 1 Green, cell 2 Wood, cell 3 John then cell 4 to be populated with The result from thia combo, lets say Matress.
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? In Excel 365 you can use FILTER function

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question, then you could use formulas such as index/match with multiple criteria, or, use a vlookup formula like this one and just concatenate your values.

Columns G through K is your reference and could be on another sheet.

Formula in cell D2:

```
    =VLOOKUP(CONCAT(A2,B2,C2),J:K,2,FALSE)
```

[image]